# mysql сравнение

Tags: mysql

Есть не простой запрос:

```
SELECT snom, podr, dolg, data_i_vremya, COUNT(dnom) as cdnom, COUNT(DISTINCT dnom) as cdnom2
    FROM fmc_xls INNER JOIN fmc_naznach 
        ON fmc_xls.snom = fmc_naznach.number 
    WHERE dnom LIKE '___________' AND 
        data_i_vremya BETWEEN '$dateforsql_start' AND '$dateforsql_end' AND 
        (dolg=2 OR dolg=3) AND 
        (prod <>'0:05') 
GROUP BY podr
ORDER BY podr
```

все работает.

Мне нужно выбирать значения которые не равны поле `prod` со значениями от `0:00` до `0:09` в mysql они хранятся как текст.

Пробовал делать так (для начала с двумя значениями):

```
SELECT snom, podr, dolg, data_i_vremya, COUNT(dnom) as cdnom , COUNT(DISTINCT dnom) as cdnom2
    FROM fmc_xls INNER JOIN fmc_naznach 
        ON fmc_xls.snom = fmc_naznach.number
    WHERE dnom LIKE '___________' AND 
        data_i_vremya BETWEEN '$dateforsql_start' AND '$dateforsql_end' AND
        (dolg=2 OR dolg=3) AND 
        (prod <>'0:05' OR prod <>'0:02') 
GROUP BY podr
ORDER BY podr
```

Но как только вставляю второе условие сравнения он просто перестает вообще сравнивать с полем `prod` как будто этого сравнения там и нет.

Comment: Ну так правильно все, `prod <>'0:05' OR prod <>'0:02'` - если `prod` не равен 0:02 или 0:05, то он удовлетворяют этому условию. Если `prod` равен 0:02, то он тоже удовлетворяет этому условию (т.к. 0:02 <> 0:05), аналогично и 0:05 удовлетворяет этому условию (т.к. 0:05 <> 0:02). Т.е. вы выбираете все значение `prod`. Т.е., чтобы условие заработало, надо сделать `prod <>'0:05' AND prod <>'0:02'`. Тогда `prod` равный 0:02 или 0:05 будут фильтроваться

Comment: Сработало. Только не знаю как пометить ваш комментарий как ответ. И еще не подскажите как проще написать конструкцию чтобы не было множества сравнений?

Comment: Комментарий не является ответом, а я не часто ответы пишу, поэтому отметить его не получится ) Про сравнения: если у вас диапазон, то можно так и выбирать: `prod > '0:02' AND prod < '0:15'`. Единственное, из-за того, что время у вас строкой, будут ошибки при сравнении вида `'2:02' > '12:01'`. Чтобы таких ошибок не было, надо сравнивать не `'2:02'`, а, например, `'02:02'`. Тогда двузначные минуты тоже сравнивались бы нормально (но не трехзначные). Но лучше бы вы время хранили числом в секундах, а к нормальному виду приводили уже в приложении, тогда таких ошибок бы не было

Comment: @BOPOH, пожалуйста, оформите написанное вами в виде ответа: это может помочь другим людям, столкнувшимся с аналогичной проблемой, найти решение.

Answer (score 1):

От Комментарии @ВОРОН

Ну так правильно все, `prod <>'0:05' OR prod <>'0:02'` - если `prod` не равен `0:02` или `0:05`, то он удовлетворяют этому условию.

Если `prod` равен 0:02, то он тоже удовлетворяет этому условию (т.к. 0:02 <> 0:05), аналогично и 0:05 удовлетворяет этому условию (т.к. 0:05 <> 0:02). Т.е. вы выбираете все значение `prod`. Т.е., чтобы условие заработало,

надо сделать `prod <>'0:05' AND prod <>'0:02'`. Тогда prod равный `0:02` или `0:05` будут фильтроваться

*Комментарий не является ответом, а я не часто ответы пишу, поэтому отметить его не получится* **Но можно ответить, нажав ОБШИЙ тогда ответ не даст репутаций**

**Про сравнения:** если у вас диапазон, то можно так и выбирать:

```
prod > '0:02' AND prod < '0:15'.
```

Единственное, из-за того, что время у вас строкой, будут ошибки при сравнении вида `'2:02' > '12:01'`. Чтобы таких ошибок не было, надо сравнивать не `'2:02'`, а, например, `'02:02'`. Тогда двузначные минуты тоже сравнивались бы нормально (но не трехзначные). Но лучше бы вы время хранили числом в секундах, а к нормальному виду приводили уже в приложении, тогда таких ошибок бы не было